# Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in Xampp after changing PHP version (PHPmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, mbstring

I changed the default PHP version to an older one (5.3.28) but when I try to jump in to PHPMyadmin I get the error

*Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\xampp2\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177*

Browsing trough this forum I found that this means I need the mbstring library

I enabled it in php.ini like this:
extension=php_mbstring.dll

But I keep receiving the same error.
I checked the extensions directory

extension_dir="C:\xampp2\php5328\ext"

and its correct, and the extension file is there as well (php_mbstring.dll)

But when I load phpinfo() I cant find any mention of mbstring.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted to load the new configuration?

Comment: Make sure you check the correct `php.ini` file.

Comment: Yes, I restarted both APACHE and  MySQL just in case, and I'm also sure I'm modifying the correct ini file

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved @.@ I was clicking config in XAMP and I thought it would for some reason open automatically the old php file (even tho Xampp is already configured to use the new one)

So yeah X) I was modifying the wrong php.ini

Thanks!